# Div-Curl Lemma for Compensated Compactness

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm looking at the proof of the following theorem in chapter 5 of Evan's [notes on Weak Convergence Methods](https://bookstore.ams.org/cbms-74):
[image]

The proof begins:

[image]

Question 1: In what topology do they mean compactness in the statement of the theorem?

Question 2: How does the computation show that $\{\text{curl }u_k\}_{k = 1}^{\infty}$ is in a compact subset of $W^{1,2}$? According to the computation shown in 5.17, it looks like he's showing $y^i_k$ is the divergence of row $i$ in $\text{curl }u_k$. But I don't see how this helps. And then why is $\{y_k\}$ in a compact subset of $L^2$ (and in what sense is it compact)?

Comment: For question 1, do you mean in (i) and (ii)? The space $W^{-1,2}(U)$ is the continuous dual of $W^{1,2}_0(U)$ so it’s a normed space with norm given by the usual norm of a functional. This norms gives you the topology

Comment: @JackT okay that's helpful, thanks!

Comment: For question 1, in addition to answer fo @JackT, for instance if $(\operatorname{div} v_k)$ and $(\operatorname{curl}w_k)$ are bounded in $L^2$, they are compact in $W^{-1,2}$. For question 2, what shows the compactness of $(\operatorname{curl}w_k)$ is not the computation (5.17), but rather the assumption (ii) and equation (5.16) since $-\Delta$ is the duality operator. And then by differentiation (5.17) gives compactness in $L^2$ (the partial differentiation is linear continuous from $W^{1,2}$ to $L^2$ and the image of a compact subset by a continuous operation is a compact subset).

Comment: Hello, I have the same question. Is my understanding correct? From $-\Delta(\text{curl} u_k) = \text{curl} w_k$ and $(-\Delta)^{-1}: W^{-1,2}\to W^{1,2}$ is bounded so $\text{curl} u_k$ is compact.